# Transformers codes or How can i find a replacement(or sellers) to this faulty transformer?

Tags: transformer

My cousin ordered a food processor called cuisinart fp-14dc from the US that is working on 110VAC while the local voltage in my country is 220v.
She plugged it without using a transformer to reduce the AC voltage to 110v and thus it is malfunctioning.
Using some of my electronics knowledge, i checked and it appears that the inner transformer inside the appliance is mulfunctioning.
I need help understanding the codes on the transformer so i can know how to find and order a replacement transformer.
Thanks in advance.

[image: transformer details as written - 120v 12v x2 class 2 transformer E180486 p3509 b21u]

Comment: Are you sure that only the transformer is faulty?  It's likely that one or more other components failed due to twice the voltage being applied.

Comment: The big blue cap is also damaged from outgassing  and the blue disc MOV has a carbon spot below it to indicate that failed abruptly, what else?  ( time for your cousin to get a new one. )

Comment: Well i checked the primary winding with a ohmeter and its not conducting so i guess its ruined but the secondary winding is conducting. 
Anyway i guess that once connecting the appliance to the AC voltage, the transformer was ruined, but the motor is sarfe since there is no way to operate the motor without the control board but the control board didnt operate since no voltage was applied cause of the ruined transformer.
My guess is that the transformer acted as a fuse.
Tomorrow i'll try to operate the control board using 12V from DC power supply and see if the whole appliace works.

Comment: "*My guess is that the transformer acted as a fuse.*" Yes but the secondary voltage would have been high for the time taken for the "fuse" to blow so the electronics may well be destroyed.

Comment: _"My guess"_ Don't guess! Measure!

Answer (score 1):

The codes on the transformer are specific to the manufacturer, and as there doesn't seem to be a clear manufacturer name you will probably never figure them out.

Once 220V has been applied then there are probably a variety of damaged components unless you got lucky and the fuse saved you. Transformers tend to fail by heat buildup which typically to takes longer than other parts to die, if the transformer is broken I would strongly advise purchasing and replacing the entire power board.